# Best way to track mobile clients which use dynamic IP addresses

Tags: java, android, mobile, tracking

I need to track users of my mobile application. When they are connected using wifi, they have a static IP address which never changes - this makes tracking easy. However, if they use their mobile network their IP addresses change on every request which makes tracking difficult.

I'm interested to see how other may have approached this problem and implemented a suitable tracking strategy in this situation?

EDIT: The solution needs to be as secure as possible to prevent users circumventing being tracked.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume by tracking you mean that a webservice knows that two differents requests are from the same user ?

If so then you just need to use the standard web tools for this : Sessions and cookies.

Make your app generate a unique id at launch and send this unique id as a cookie or variable with every requests you make to your webservice. This way you really uniquely identifie them.

Also note : Wifi can give you a static Ip address inside the network in which the device is connected bu not on the Internet. The external(public) ip you can retrieve is the one of your router. Most of the time and with most internet providers, if the connection fails for some reason, the router will have a new ip affected to it. Beside if two persons are using the same router to connect to your webservice, they will have the same public ip address.

**EDIT** : The usual way of being more secure is the one used by most websites : The UID used to authenticate a user is generated by the web server(and not the app) on the first request/authentication of a session. This UID is passed from the webserver to the app that then resend it with every requests. This limits "session stealing" to the duration of the session. 
Request that do not send a UID or a UID that does not exists in the database are illegitimate.

**EDIT 2** : The OP added in the comment below that what he really wants is limits the number of requests made by a single user in a certain time. Pratically, this means uniquely identifying a device. 
One way to do this is to compute a UID on the device at first launch and store it on the device. Then send this UID to the webservice with each request. The webservice will be responsible to limit the number of hits by a specific UID.

*Note  :* Be careful of how you generate the UID. Android as a [Android_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) but it is known to be null sometimes and to change over time. This guy seems to have found a [not to easily spoofable Device UID](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=get-unique-identifier-android) :

Comment: You assume correctly, I want to track requests from the same user. Also I need a "secure" solution that will prevent users from circumventing tracking. I should have added that to the original question.

Comment: Okay so when a user makes a request to my server, I return a UID with the response (and record his IP along with the UID?), I must be missing something as the user can simply change his IP for subsequent requests to generate a new UID?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question from the beginning. Maybe you should edit your question to try to explain what it is you are trying to do. I thought you wanted to track a user during a session to make sure whatever he is doing is only affecting is account. But now you seem to be looking for a solution to track a user for the life of the application. Please be more specific on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I'll try and explain this better. I have a web service that I wish to limit the number of requests per second any user can make, I.e. no more than 5 requests per minute.

I need to find a solution that will enable me to track users requests and ensure they cannot exceed this limit even if their IP changes between each request.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the device id:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()

Edit: Or create an UUID the first time the app launches, more suggestions and information here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: The device ID requires the READ_PHONE_STATE permission which I really don't want to use. I guess I could use a UUID but it could be easily spoofed. I probably should have added to my original question that I also need a solution that is difficult to circumvent by users.

Comment: If you know that all devices have wifi I guess you could store their mac address when that is available. How would an app-generated UUID easily be spoofed by your users?